# tensorflow-federated: TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I am using `tensorflow-federated` version 0.28. I tried to implement [build_weighted_fed_avg_with_optimizer_schedule](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/algorithms/build_weighted_fed_avg_with_optimizer_schedule) but I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Desktop/FL/fedopt.py", line 340, in <module>
    iterative_process = build_weighted_fed_avg_with_optimizer_schedule(
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/fl/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/algorithms/fed_avg_with_optimizer_schedule.py", line 276, in build_weighted_fed_avg_with_optimizer_schedule
    client_work = build_scheduled_client_work(model_fn, client_learning_rate_fn,
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/fl/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/algorithms/fed_avg_with_optimizer_schedule.py", line 98, in build_scheduled_client_work
    whimsy_optimizer = optimizer_fn(1.0)
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

My code is as follows:

```
iterative_process = build_weighted_fed_avg_with_optimizer_schedule(
    model_fn,
    client_learning_rate_fn = lambda x: 0.001,
    client_optimizer_fn=lambda: optimizers.Adam(learning_rate= client_lr, beta_1 = 0.9, beta_2 = 0.999,epsilon = 1e-07),
    server_optimizer_fn=lambda: optimizers.SGD(learning_rate= server_lr), 
    use_experimental_simulation_loop=True)
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

In your code above, you have `lambda` set to accept a parameter `x`:

```
client_learning_rate_fn = lambda x: 0.001
```

Are you looking to pass in some `x` to be manipulated by `0.001`, say a multiplication? See below:

```
client_learning_rate_fn = lambda x: x*0.001
```

Edits: fixing grammatical errors

Comment: Hi @Alex, thanks for the reply. In the documentation it is `client_learning_rate_fn: Callable[[int], float]`. "A callable accepting an integer round number and returning a float to be used as a learning rate for the optimizer. The client work will call `optimizer_fn(learning_rate_fn(round_num))` where `round_num` is the integer round number."

Comment: Your error states that you need to pass something into your callable lambda function if is declared with a parameter. In this case you need a value to be rounded (unclear if you need it rounded up or down, decimal places, etc.), so maybe something like `lambda x: round(x)` is needed to create said rounded integer to generate the learning rate.